# Scroll up to Load More Data in angular1

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I want to add scroll up to load more data in div. I want to implement it on message detail screen where user can scroll up to load more message.

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("myDIV").scrollTop === 0) {
      // call api to fetch data
    }
}
```

I have implemented this it's working fine. But evet fire multiple time. If i have to call event only one time.

Comment: use [anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Comment: I voted to close this question as off topic, as the statement "Please share any demo" implies that no effort was made to solve the problem, and the question seeks to find a ready made solution from a 3rd party source instead.  This site is not intended for recommendations requests, due the fact that answers to these questions tend to be opinionated or spam.

Answer (score 0):

Attach `onscroll` event handler on div first then use it like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("myDIV").scrollTop === 0) {
      // call api to fetch data
    }
}
```